# HTML audio player timeline functionality add

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, audio

I am trying to add HTML audio player. I applied a code there play pause working. I need to add timeline functionality here. But don't know how to do that. Here another problem also I don't know how can I apply play pause in same button. Please help me. Below is my code. [sample](https://jsfiddle.net/lemonkazi/nL0dykgq/)

```css
#audioplayer{
 width: 480px;
 height: 60px;
 margin: 50px auto auto auto;
border: solid;
}

#pButton{
    height:60px; 
    width: 60px;
    border: none;
    background-size: 50% 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    float:left;
    outline:none;
}

.play, .play:hover, .pause:focus{background: url('https://img.pranavc.in/20') ;}
.pause, .pause:hover, .play:focus{background: url('https://img.pranavc.in/30') ;}

#timeline{
 width: 400px;
 height: 20px;
 margin-top: 20px;
 float: left;
 border-radius: 15px;
 background: rgba(0,0,0,.3);
  
}
#playhead{
 width: 18px;
 height: 18px;
 border-radius: 50%;
 margin-top: 1px;
 background: rgba(0, 0, 0,1);

}
```

```html
<audio id="player" src="https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-1.mp3"></audio>
<div id="audioplayer">
 <button id="pButton" class="play" onclick="document.getElementById('player').play()"></button> 
  <button id="pButton" class="pause" onclick="document.getElementById('player').pause()"></button> 
 <div id="timeline">    
   <div id="playhead"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use javascript, and change the dom and css.
You need to learn audio event and property.

```js
var audio = document.getElementById("player");
var btn = document.getElementById("pButton");
btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
   if (audio.paused) {
       audio.play();
       btn.classList.remove("pause");
       btn.classList.add("play");
   } else  {
       audio.pause();
       btn.classList.remove("play");
       btn.classList.add("pause");
   }
});
var playhead = document.getElementById("playhead"); audio.addEventListener("timeupdate", function(){ var duration = this.duration; var currentTime = this.currentTime; var percentage = (currentTime / duration) * 100; playhead.style.left = percentage * 4 + 'px'; });
```

```css
#audioplayer{
    position: relative;
 width: 480px;
 height: 60px;
 margin: 50px auto auto auto;
    border: solid;
}

#pButton{
    height:60px; 
    width: 60px;
    border: none;
    float:left;
    outline:none;
}

#pButton.pause {
    background: url('https://img.pranavc.in/20') no-repeat;
    background-size: 56px;
    background-position: center;
}

#pButton.play {
    background: url('https://img.pranavc.in/30') no-repeat;
    background-size: 56px;
    background-position: center;
}

#timeline{
 width: 400px;
 height: 20px;
 margin-top: 20px;
 float: left;
 border-radius: 15px;
 background: rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    position: relative;
}
#playhead{
 width: 18px;
 height: 18px;
 border-radius: 50%;
 margin-top: 1px;
 background: rgba(0, 0, 0,1);
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<audio id="player" src="https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-1.mp3"></audio>
<div id="audioplayer">
 <button id="pButton" class="pause"></button>
 <div id="timeline">    
 <div id="playhead"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Is this playing music or not?

Comment: try this, but you have to use javascript code, and change the html dom.

Comment: you want to play music, you have to click the play button, if you want to play  the music at the fitst, change the code

Comment: Thanks nice answer. Here I need little bit more to work just increase timeline when playing and off when paused.

Comment: var playhead = document.getElementById("playhead");
audio.addEventListener("timeupdate", function(){
   var duration = this.duration;
   var currentTime = this.currentTime;
   var percentage = (currentTime / duration) * 100;
   
   playhead.style.left = percentage * 4 + 'px';
});

Answer (score 0):

You need to add Javascript code on page to have this functionality. You can extract the code you want from this code (Nicely explained).

https://www.developphp.com/video/JavaScript/Audio-Play-Pause-Mute-Buttons-Tutorial

https://www.developphp.com/video/JavaScript/Audio-Seek-and-Volume-Range-Slider-Tutorial

Comment: Thanks for answer. I applied code from your suggested page. But can't work from my side. https://jsfiddle.net/lemonkazi/jpn53tfs/

Answer (score 0):

```
<audio controls>
    <source src="Link.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

Try the above Code. **Note:** The audio tag is not supported in Internet Explorer 8 and earlier versions.
Check this link : http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_audio.asp

Comment: I know this solution. But I need to apply design so I did in different way. Thanks for your answer.